# Excel 2007 vs 2010 disabling file save prompt

Tags: excel, vba

We used the following code in Excel 2007 to disable the file save prompt:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub
```

After upgrading to Excel 2010 this code no longer works.  I have researched and tried all of the following code with no luck:

```
Private Sub Auto_Close()
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub

Application.DisplayAlerts = false

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub



Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  If WasOpened2 Then Workbooks(FilenameNoPath(FoundFiles(i))).Close False 
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Any other ideas are appreciated.

Comment: There must be something else going on. I just opened a new workbook in xl2010, put the `ThisWorkbook.Saved = True` into a `Workbook_BeforeClose`, , saved it to give it a name then changed some values and it closed with Ctrl+F4 without a problem.